# Passing object parameter to extended AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

GoodDay everybody.
I wrote a class which extends `AsyncTask`.

```
public class InitTransaction extends AsyncTask<TransactionParameters, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(TransactionParameters... params) {
        // I do some stuff here
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // I do some more stuff
    }
}
```

The class is called with:

```
TransactionParameters transParams = new TransactionParameters(param1, param2);
InitTransaction initTransaction = new InitTransaction();
initTransaction.execute(transParams);
```

The problem is that i get an error while passing the object to the task:

[![No method?][1]][1]

Anybody knows where the problem may be?

### EDIT

Fixed that problem now I have another one.
As soon as I execute `initTransaction.execute(transParams);` boom!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.infovision.elcam_02, PID: 17443
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870) 
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:828)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
        at com.infovision.elcam_02.MainActivity$InitTransaction.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:648)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:595)
        at com.infovision.elcam_02.MainActivity.scanCode(MainActivity.java:133)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Comment: That's quite weird. Did you try to restart Android studio? Are imports in order?

Comment: I tried closing and opening Android studio. I'll try to restart the computer. Imports are fine.

Comment: Yup... I just had to restart the computer. You gotta love AndroidStudio

Comment: That's my thoughts exactly when something just breaks out of thin air and vanishes like this...